# How to sculpt feathers in blender?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, 3d-printing, sculpt

i just can't figure out how to sculpt feathers on top of each other in blender ? my problem is , that the previous drawn feather will collide with new one , i want to find a way to sculpt them on top of each other , currently Im using clay brush to make the second feather on top but thats not accurate , i'll be very happy if anyone can help me on this one .
I uploaded a gif file so you guys can better realize what i mean .

[image]

all sort of guidance are welcome .

---

best regards .

Comment: Just for update , the brushes that i used are free and they're here at artstation : https://www.artstation.com/a/10676663

Comment: That is probably not possible to achieve... what I mean is that when you use height map brush it gives your object height.. one is 0.1 and one part is 0.8... now if you add another feather it will be 0.2 and 1.6 and this is problem because for your purposes you would need to sculpt it to 0.1 and 0.8 and at the time you are going to use second feather, 1st feather need to be set to same value like 1.0, then you would achieve what you want, lower feather at 0.1 and 0.8 and top one at 1.1 and 1.8... I think this is impossible but maybe someone knows the way to go around it

Comment: @MikoCG Thanks a lot for your effort , It would be a miracle that someone knows how to work around , due to the link of artstation if you download it , i do have the geometries too , but i want to sculpt with multires so i keep the rig of my bird , but blender does not have add brush or insert brush , if there was a way to work around in that way it could be good . 

Comment: what about add feathers with particle system? Didn't try to make a bird like that but maybe it would be possible with comb

Comment: @MikoCG just another problem that i have with particle system , it just works fine , but if i choose custom geometry it won't bend the feathers , if there was a way to bend custom geo like path's bend , it'll do the job ,but sculpting is better btw , cause i have controlled mesh resolution